# Get selected value of spinner doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm having trobles with a Spinner, I need recover values to string of this Spinner type from array from resource, I'm trying to Log the value as String and Is not possible, please help

Greetens

David

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Log.v("SPINNER", item);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        String str = "";
    }

});
```

Comment: What is the output of Log.v("Spinner", item); ? Did you debug the app at this lines?

Comment: what do u get from the log?

Comment: Empty... nothing in log

Comment: Make sure that the level of shown logs in your logcat would show this entry. (verbose, error, info, warning, etc.) Debug the app to this onItemSelected Listener if its getting called.

Comment: id recommend to use System.Out, and use a filter to find it on the console. And have you tried accessing the Adapter directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried querying your adapter directly in onItemSelected e.g.

```
String item = adapter(position).toString();
```